# How do I implement caching in C++?

Tags: c++, caching, memory-management

Suppose, I have a very large `std::map< unsigned int, Foo > FooDB`, which holds `Foo` objects in memory, retrievable by their ID. Now there might be more `Foo` objects than there is memory available to store them. So I'd like to have the following construct:

- retrieve `Foo` object with ID *x* from `FooDB`
- if object *x* is in `FooDB`, return it
- if it isn't, load it from HD, try to store it in `FooDB` for further queries

  - there is enough memory available: add it to `FooDB`
  - there is not enough memory: free some space by removing from `FooDB` objects not in use (oldest query timestamp)

I'd like to reserve some memory for the `FooDB` and I can't tell, how many `Foo` objects can be stored in it, as they differ in size.

Any ideas on how to implement this?

**EDIT**

My basic problem is: how can I tell a `std::map`'s size in memory? All heap objects stored in it included, of course. How can I know when the *not enough memory* part has been reached?

Comment: There are entire companies that make billions of dollars just doing this. So it's kind of a big topic.

Comment: At its simplest, your algorithm is directly convertible from pseudocode to code. So just go on with it. But for a more elaborate solution, Mysticial is just right. You may want a database engine.

Comment: Specically, google nosql and key-value storage. A number of them use memorymapping for their implementation (given enough memory, they can operate entirely in-memory).

Comment: What are the performance criteria, number of items? Can't you just use sqlite or <insert any reasonable disk based db here> and let the OS handle the disk/memory caching? If it turns out it's too slow stick an LRU cache on top e.g. http://code.google.com/p/lru-cache-cpp/

Comment: @Mystical: I don't need sophisticated predictions on which objects should be deleted. A very simple method will do it. Databases are an option, I'm just interested if there is an easy DIY-solution.

Comment: There is no way to get the actual memory usage of a non-trivial variable. But you can make a guess. Add a method to `Foo` to guess its memory usage. Don't care about a byte more or less. Find out what the biggest chunks are and try to get them right and add some offset to cover the smaller pieces and the overhead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no way to ask an object what its size is, other than sizeof(). You said that sizeof() won't work because the Foo objects don't have a fixed size. In that case, if you can modify Foo, then maybe your Foo class can keep track of its memory footprint internally. And if you can't modify Foo, you might be able to write an external function that can deduce the memory footprint.

Fundamentally, it would be very difficult for the language/compiler/runtime to know how big a dynamically-sized object is because it doesn't know which allocations belong to the object. A simple solution, just recursively sum all of the things that it's members point to, will fail on anything that has a pointer to an object that it doesn't "own". Another simple solution, to keep track of all of the allocations done between when the constructor starts and when it returns, will fail for anything that makes allocations after the constructor is called.

You might want to just use the number of Foo's as your cache limit instead of the memory size. Unless you know a lot about the memory availability and usage of the entire system, a cap based on memory size would be arbitrary as well. And if you know a lot about the memory usage of the entire system, you could just use the overall memory availability to determine when to release objects from the cache.

Comment: I could keep track of the `Foo` object's sizes. But there's also an overhead inside `std::map` for example, because it has to store a tree structure somewhere for the index. I don't get that with `sizeof()` or tracking my object's sizes.

Comment: @Ben If you're concerned about the size of the tree structure, either the Foo objects are very small, or you have a need for a really accurate measurement. If the Foo objects are small, go with a cap on the number of Foo objects and you should be fine. Otherwise, if you need a really accurate measurement, I'd be interested to know why.

Comment: It depends on what you call small. Foo's size is between 10 and 300KB.
I realized that the memory consumed by my process was higher than I expected. I don't know where it's gone exactly, I just explain it to myself with the index overhead, as you have it with every database. And I don't want to risk an out-of-memory exception, that's all.

Answer (score 4):

It's fairly straightforward.

Just place a reference to each in-memory Foo instance in FooDB in a sorted linked list ordered by age.

When you load a new item for the first time into memory add it to the front of the list.

When you read/modify an item move it from the middle of list to the front of the list.

When you need to delete an old item to make space pop it off the back of the list.

For example:

```
typedef shared_ptr<Foo> PFoo;

class Foo
{
    ...
    list<PFoo>::iterator age;
};

typedef map< unsigned int, PFoo > FooDB;
FooDB foodb; 

list<PFoo> ages;

void LoadFoo(PFoo foo)
{
    ages.push_front(foo);
}

void ReadFoo(PFoo foo)
{
    ...
    ages.erase(foo->age);
    ages.push_front(foo);
}

void MakeSpace()
{
    PFoo foo = ages.back();
    ages.pop_back();
    DeleteFoo(foo);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the easy part where I handle the timestamps. But how do I know if my map is full?

Comment: No don't use a map, it is far less efficient (O(logN) vs O(1)).  Also you don't need timestamps, see above.  Use a sorted linked list as I described.  You can tell how many items are in memory with ages.size().  In the LoadFoo function you can just say `if ages.size() > MAX then MakeSpace()`

Comment: Yes, but the `Foo`'s don't have fixed size. So I don't know how much memory they actually use.

Comment: So you can't test at runtime how much space a Foo instance uses?

Comment: If you want to measure how much space your process has allocated then there are platform specific ways to get this information.  So you could periodically test if this is over some limit and then call MakeSpace until it goes below a certain threshold.

Comment: If you want to test how much space Foos alone use you could modify them to use a MemoryPool class that keeps track of this.

Comment: I'd like to know, how big `FooDB` is and free some space if it reaches for example 6GB. MemoryPool classes sound good. I guess I can alloc 6GB for the pool and check when it's full?

Comment: Tomazos-Fathomling: erasing isn't O(1), it's O(n). With every query I have to check, if the object is in the list. That's why I would use a map.

Comment: @Ben: You know already whether the item is cached in memory because of its membership of the FooDB map.  I was assuming that was the purpose of FooDB.  (Further you should use an unordered_map for FooDB as this will give you O(1) performance instead of O(logN)).  If that is not the purpose of FooDB than create a seperate unordered_set<int> that keeps track of the IDs of elements that are loaded in memory and update it when you load and close items.  The sorted list is for keeping track of the ages of the items.